# Can a bad last semester prevent me from getting into grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, canada

I submitted my graduate application form  for a university in January, even saying I would graduate 'with honours'. I'm not sure how I was suppose to know what I would graduate with, but what I wrote down before almost feels like a complete lie at this point.

Now I am in my final semester of my undergraduate degree and it is burning me hard. My program pretty much cornered me into the 2nd most sadistic set of courses I have taken. I have an average of 3-4 (3-5 page) assignments due every week, and the content itself is the type of stuff you need to allow yourself to digest (if I had the time). My grades are all over the place, anywhere from 30%-80%. The TAs marking them are cruel, with an all or nothing marking scheme.

I realize this may be a post to vent some frustration I feel, but I am genuinely worried about my future at this point. These are the very courses of subjects I wish to go into, and an outside observer might look at my marks and feel my work ethic and intelligence was simply inadequate. My other semesters have been ~80% and I don't exactly have any research experience to back my case.

Comment: It is unlikely, but possible. Most decisions will be made by the time final grades are posted. A fair number of people crash in their final semester, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Admissions decisions will be made based on your application materials and any sort of interview process that a given program uses; this will all likely happen before the semester is over so you won't have any grades finalized before then.

If you're accepted, you will get an offer that states reasons the offer can potentially be withdrawn. It's likely there to be some sort of clause that indicates the offer is conditional on completion of your current degree, and it may be written more broadly to something like "satisfactory academic progress". So yes, if your bad semester prevents you from graduating, it likely will prevent your admission. There's a chance possibility that a poor semester that doesn't prevent graduation could also affect your admission, but that will be entirely up to the program and nothing can be guaranteed. Given the ongoing pandemic I'd guess programs would be more forgiving of a recent slide. However, you'll want to make sure that you are able to be successful in the program, and if you are in courses now that will be relevant to your future you'll need to be sure you're staying on top of the material, no matter what your assessments look like. You also may see this as an opportunity to polish your time management skills, as these will be important in graduate school as well as in your current courses.

Comment: Yes, finishing the degree is essential. Most offers would be withdrawn for a non-graduate. It is hard to imagine an exception.